# UIView inside subclass as an @IBOutlet while in superclass being instance property, not an outlet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, iboutlet

I have a superclass where I am instantiating a UIView as a property with a red background color. In my subclass I want to override this property, but make it as an IBOutlet. Is that possible? So I want all my subclasses to have a view in Storyboard with a red background by overriding superclass's view. I am trying to implement this logic to more complex concept, but I used UIView just for simplicity. Here is the code which is not working:

```
class SuperClass: UIViewController {
    lazy var myView: UIView! = {
        let aView = UIView()
        aView.backgroundColor = .red
        return aView
    }()
}

class SubclassVC: SuperClass {

    @IBOutlet override var myView: UIView! {
        get { return super.myView }
        set {}
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's not working?

Comment: Sure. In this particular example @IBOutlet is connected to a UIView created inside storyboard. This view's background does not become red when I am doing this: "get { return super.myView }"

Comment: @Caleb The thing i am trying to solve is: 
1. I want to have one superclass, who is a subclass of UIViewController with a UIView property instantiated programmatically. (with a colour, borderWidth, etc. let's say) . 
2. I want to have 2 subclasses of superclass.  
3. One of the subclasses should be instantiated programmatically and one from storyboard.  
4. I want both subclasses to have a UIView consumed from a superclass. (without duplicating the view in each subclass, but use the one from superclass)   

P.S. Hope I was clear enough

Comment: *use the one from superclass* Then why bother with an outlet? Just remove your override of `myVar` from `SubclassVC` and you're there. Each subclass will have a view, instantiated programmatically by the superclass, and with a red background.

Comment: Definitely! But I was wondering if it's possible to override as @IBOutlet

Comment: To what end? Are you going to connect something to that overridden property? If so, then wouldn't you expect the overridden property to override what's provided by the parent class? I'm just having a hard time understanding the actual goal. Perhaps you could tell us about the real problem and why the apparent solution isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

`IBOutlet` is just a hint to Interface Builder. IBOutlets can be anything. `UIView, UIButton, UITextView,` etc.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
```

In the above code the myView is only a reference to the already created view in the Storyboard or XIB

> Role of IBOutlet:
>
> An object can communicate with other objects in an application by
>   sending messages to outlets. An outlet can reference any object in an
>   application: user interface objects such as text fields and buttons,
>   model objects (usually instances of custom classes), and even the
>   application object itself. Outlets are special instance variables
>   because they can be set in Interface Builder.
>
> And:
>
> Note: IBOutlet is a null-defined macro that the C preprocessor removes
>   at compile time. Interface Builder uses it to identify outlet
>   declarations so that it can display them when connecting outlets
>   visually.
>
> In summary:
>
> IBOutlets can reference pretty much anything. They are just a hint to
>   Interface Builder which lets you set their value when you load the
>   XIB. In fact, the text IBOutlet means so little outside of the
>   Interface Builder world, that it gets stripped from the final product
>   because it's completely non-functional for any purpose other than
>   helping out Interface Builder.
>
> I'd go back and check out some of the other things you were hooking up
>   as IBOutlets, and you'll surely discover they actually do have some
>   real type.

**Instead you can try the following**

```
    class SuperClass: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!{
            didSet {
                myView.backgroundColor = .red
            }
        }

    }

    class SubclassVC: SuperClass {

        func updateMyView() {
//Note : You can customise the view and it is available as IBOutlet
            myView.backgroundColor = .orange
        }
    }
```

> Using inheritance you can connect the outlet to base class and use it
>   in the child class and you can update it as you need